# Firebase Difference b/w putBytes or putfile which is fast uploading?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Cloud Storage for Firebase. I have little confusion how to upload imagefile in fastest manner using Byte Array or using file

```
try {
               Uri uri = Uri.parse(UriList.get(Imagecount_update));

            bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uri);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.d("PrintIOExeception","*****     "+e.toString());

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            StorageReference riversRef = mStorageReference.child("images/" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            UploadTask uploadTask;
            uploadTask = riversRef.putBytes(data);
```

(or)

```
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(data);
```

Which one is fast way to upload images  `uploadTask = riversRef.putBytes(data);` or `uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(data);`?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of which one is faster. They both DO different things. putFile uploads a file from a URI (a file hosted on the internet, or the path to a file on the clients local system, prefixed with "file://") meaning it will download the file to the server. putBytes accepts the bytes from a physical byte[] produced by the file, and given to the server by you (or another client).

[See here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) the API shows the difference.

Also, there is putStream, which can accept things like a memory stream, which COULD essentially make the processing of the file faster on the client side, but as far as speed of the actual upload it is completely dependent on connection speeds of the client and the server, and no one function will upload/download any faster than the other.

But, in conclusion, to answer your question, I personally would just use putFile() for images, since putFile() most likely handles the byte[] logic for you on the back end.

Comment: Can I use `putStream()` for uploading images??

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I would imagine so, as long as you have a stream of the image in memory.